# Need template for PhD Thesis

Tags: thesis

Thanking all for the replies, here is the corrected question...

It is bit annoying once you expect a template ZIPPED file to include what it needs and still prompting you for files etc and giving errors such as "...not found ...".

I have been writing articles using Latex and have Tex files and Bibtex files working fine.

Now I need to write thesis for which I want to add various features such as Chapter styles and various lists (all things typical of a thesis).

The best I thought was to look at templates. I downloaded many and tried to run them. They prompt for installations of styles etc. which I accordingly follow but mostly it happens that at the end, I get some kind of error. 
Mostly asking for "...SO_AND_SO.tex file not found " or "...Figure\SO_AND_SO...not found"

Therefore, here I request for a TEMPLATE that includes all whats needed.

I am using :

WinEdt 8.1 on windows 8.1.

P.S.For figures, I am more easy/familiar with EPS format and calling a PDF inside has never been a good experience.

Will be grateful for the help and thank again for all the replies I received to my unclear question.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any particular specification to follow?

Comment: if your department has a specific style, use that, otherwise just use `\documentclass{book}` and add packages as you need them.

Comment: `\documentclass{book}  \begin{document} \chapter{My beautiful thesis} \end{document}`;-)

Comment: `\documentclass{report}` ;-)

Comment: No you REALLY don't need a template for PhD thesis.

Comment: Note that if the 'lots of installations' means e.g. a TeX distribution and an editor, *that*, at least, is not the fault of the template. The errors are a different matter.

Comment: check `Overleaf` or `shareLaTeX`, if you don't want to be troubled with installations

Comment: You really don't need a template and you really shouldn't use one. You obviously need some general LaTeX knowledge. Anyway, here is one: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

Comment: This template runs out of the box: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/doriens-phd-thesis-template/ntgfsykpsrwb#.WZ-f74oRVTY

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what OS you are running or what you mean by "lots of installations". I like to use [LyX](https://www.lyx.org), a LaTeX editor with a graphical user interface (I especially like how equations are displayed). If you are using Windows, one of the binaries available for download is a bundle which makes the installation incredibly easy - in addition to LyX it will install a LaTeX distribution (MikTeX) and bibliography manager (JabRef).

I quite like this [LyX thesis template](https://github.com/adefazio/lyx-thesis-template) available on GitHub. The features which appeal most to me are:

1. I found it very easy to setup - just download the repository and follow the instructions on the blog.
2. You can use separate LyX files and/or folders for each chapter. Smaller chapter files are great for focusing on specific areas of your work and separate folders are nice for viewing only images relevant in that chapter. I find it especially useful when you're not certain yet in which order you'd like to present the work.
3. The resulting pdf has a very nice layout. Here is an example of how a chapter would look... [image: sample chapter preview]

If LyX does not suit your fancy, maybe you should try using an online LaTeX editor such as Overleaf - numerous [thesis templates](https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/thesis) are available. Going this way also makes it very easy to share your work and collaborate with others.

Comment: One should probably mention that LyX is a tool for experienced LaTeX users.

Comment: The repo you are linking to does not have a license and hence is not free to use. https://github.com/adefazio/lyx-thesis-template/issues/1